# Java. IO. Проблема с закрытием записи файла

Tags: java, io

У меня два метода на стороне сервера и на стороне клиента. Файл должен закачиваться на сервер. И он закачивается но вместо того чтобы перекачав файл выйти из метода он продолжает туда писать, но уже не тот файл который я отправлял а текстовые команды для сервера.

Вопрос как сказать методу принимающему что передача файла закончилась? Или отправляющему что файл закончился?

В общем что-то я запутался, помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Вот принимающий метод:

```
// загружаем файл из сокета и записываем на свой диск
    private boolean download(String path, FileInputStream in) {
        File target;
        try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(target = new File(path))) {

            int data;
            while ((data = in.read()) != -1) {
                out.write(data);
            }

            if (target.exists()) // до сюда никогда не доходит застревает в цикле
                return true;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

И отправляющий:

```
// отправка файла в сокет
    private void upload(String path, FileOutputStream out) {
        try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(path))) {

            int data;
            while ((data = in.read()) != -1) {
                out.write(data);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: могу порекомендовать следующее. у вас там идет непрерывный поток байтов из сокета. сначало вы отправляете размер файла в байтах, файла. потом шлете сам файл, отсчитывая количество байт. при достижении нужной цифры закрываете запись в файл и выходите из метода.

Comment: @Павел, Ты передаешь пока не -1. И саму -1 не отправляешь. Следовательно сервер её не получат. Переделай цикл на клиенте на do-while

Comment: Почему не передаю ? in.read() должен вернуть -1 когда нечего читать. Разве нет?

Comment: Неа ты же её не записал

Comment: >> Максим Дробышев << ну конечно! Я понял спасибо!